# Trying to make a Adapter class to choose .Java file depending on firmware version

Tags: java, android, backwards-compatibility, android-1.5-cupcake

What I did was create two .java files. One that can compile and run on a 1.5 phone (SDK3) and then one that works on 2.0(SDK5) So for this example i'll call the 1.5 file ExampleOld and the new one Example. I was wondering if i just made activity like this if it would work sort of like a "portal" and pick the activity to load depending on the SDK so there is no crash or compile errors. Are there any changes I should make to my code? Maybe anyone out there that's had to do this before. thanks!

```
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ExamplePortal extends Activity { 
    int sdk=new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (sdk<5) {
        Intent v = new Intent(this, ExampleOld.class);
        startActivity(v);
    }

    else {
        Intent v = new Intent(this, Example.class);
        startActivity(v);
    } 
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing (correct me if I'm wrong) is trying to maintain backwards compatibility while making use of new APIs if the user is running a newer android version. The best way to do this is to follow the tutorial Google posted [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html). This avoids any verification issues and is really the best way to do stuff imho.

Comment: I was looking at that. I'm just still pretty new to java. I had a hard time following that. So, I tried to come up with something I understood.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this decision in a Factory Class to avoid having these if-else statements all over the codebase.